# ArrayList object and its iterator object not working

Tags: java, collections

As the heading mentions, the ArrayList and its iterator not working. Not able to figure why.
The ArrayList should expect Employees and it is getting it. Then why the iterator is not giving proper objects?Any help?

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

class Employee implements Serializable
{
    private int empid;
    private String name,desig;
    private double salary;
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1;
    
    Employee(int empid,String name,String desig, double salary)
    {
        this.empid=empid;
        this.name=name;
        this.desig=desig;
        this.salary=salary;
    }
    
    Employee()
    {}

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Employee [empid=" + empid + ", name=" + name + ", desig=" + desig + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
    }
    
}
    
    /**
     * This class is used for checking the serializability of the objects.
     */
public class CollectionsAndSerializabilityPractice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Employee> listOfEmployees= new ArrayList<Employee>();
        
        for(int i=1; i<=4; i++)
        {
            listOfEmployees.add(new Employee(i, "Employee"+i, "Manager", 25000+i));
        }
        
        System.out.println("Before serialisation:");
        
        Iterator<Employee> iterate=listOfEmployees.iterator();
        while(iterate.hasNext())
        {
            iterate.next().toString();
            System.out.println();
        }
        
        try(FileOutputStream FOS= new FileOutputStream("Output.txt");)
        {
            ObjectOutputStream OOS=new ObjectOutputStream(FOS);
            
            OOS.writeObject(listOfEmployees);
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        try(FileInputStream FIS= new FileInputStream("Output.txt");)
        {
            ObjectInputStream OIS=new ObjectInputStream(FIS);
            
         listOfEmployees=(List<Employee>)OIS.readObject();
         iterate=listOfEmployees.iterator();
            
            System.out.println("After deserialisation:");

            while(iterate.hasNext())
            {
                iterate.next().toString();
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    }

}
```

I am not able to understand why the toString method is not working? Can somebody explain to me about this issue in some detail? Any good explanation is highly appreciated.
output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
        while(iterate.hasNext())
        {
            iterate.next().toString();
            System.out.println();
        }
```

to

```
        while(iterate.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(iterate.next().toString);
        }
```

You only printed newlines with your no-arg `System.out.println();` statement. You never assigned the result of `iterate.next().toString();` to anything, so it was lost.

Comment: OMG, how come I acted to stupidly? I forgot SOP()? ohh, sh**!!! Thanx man, I checked everything, except the SOP().